# How to access large amount of csv files Data from aws EC2 instance to in multiple Spot Instances?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spot-instances

I have 5 years of Stock market data, and strategies which I regularly run on my local machine, but I felt that my local machine takes so much time for processing that data. so I decided to process my data in was server.
So I did little research about EC2 instances.
So I found that I can store my raw stock market data in Ec2 Instance and install Jupyter notebook and python modules in EC2 instances.
and run/process my data on multiple Spot Instances. which take less time for processing data, and as well as it will cost me efficiency.
but I don't understand How can I access data and connect Ec2 instances and spot instances to each other.

so please someone can help me?

Comment: "connect Ec2 instances and spot instances to each other" - what do you mean by that? Sadly your question is not clear.

Comment: @Marcin I just want to use that data which is stored in EC2 instance, and process that data with the help of python code on Spot Instances.

Comment: If you are using multiple Amazon EC2 instances, then a good approach would be to store the data in Amazon S3. Then, when it is needed on an EC2 instance, it can be downloaded from S3. This way, data will not be lost of the Spot Instance is terminated.

Comment: As @JohnRotenstein said, use S3. You could also use EFS.